# MySQL DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE + SUM Function

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to build a table that summarizes my data from "cache" table.
Because i'm planning to run my aggregation query every few minutes (by cron or by event, not really matter), and in order to avoid duplicated rows, I want rows that already exist in my summary table will be updated (I've configured a unique key), so the value from my "cache" table would just be integrated with the exist value.

Here is my query:

```
INSERT INTO  `ReportsSummary` 
                (`date`,
                `txtID`,
                `webID`,
                `GEO`,
                `OSS`,
                `impressions`,
                `clicks`)

SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date ,'%Y-%m-%d'),txtID,webID, GEO, OSS,
    SUM( if(actionType = '1',1,0) ) as add_impressions,
    SUM( if(actionType = '2',1,0) ) as add_clicks
FROM `CacheReports` as t GROUP BY txtID,webID,GEO,OSS

ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
impressions = impressions + (`t`.`add_impressions`),
clicks = clicks + (`t`.`add_clicks`);
```

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no add_impressions and add_clicks columns in table t (CacheReports) - it's your aggregate that has them. Use the below corrected query:

```
INSERT INTO  `ReportsSummary` 
                (`date`,
                `txtID`,
                `webID`,
                `GEO`,
                `OSS`,
                `impressions`,
                `clicks`)

SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date ,'%Y-%m-%d'),txtID,webID, GEO, OSS,
    SUM( if(actionType = '1',1,0) ) as add_impressions,
    SUM( if(actionType = '2',1,0) ) as add_clicks
FROM `CacheReports` as t GROUP BY txtID,webID,GEO,OSS) AS `u`

ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
impressions = impressions + `u`.`add_impressions`,
clicks = clicks + `u`.`add_clicks`;
```